# Grabbing the HTML within a div / class / id from another website

Tags: wordpress, html

I'm currently creating a website using Wordpress. On one of the pages I want to extract news articles from another website, but I don't want to use iframe (I want to style it with css), nor do I want the entire page, just what's within the text of the article.

I'm pretty new to coding (which is one of the reason why I'm using wordpress), so I'm not sure how to go about it. I've looked around online, but the answers are either different from what I need, or they're far beyond my understanding. If there's some sort of wordpress plugin that does the job for me, that'd be great, but otherwise I'd be grateful to be pointed in the right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look for RSS feed, it might contain the content you need and its easier to grab things from RSS than from HTML. Or simply download the page via any programming language into object and find the element with either REGEX or Xpath.

Or use WordPress WebScraper plugin: [Here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-web-scrapper/)

Comment: The articles themselves don't have an RSS feed (though perplexingly the homepage of the site does). 

How would downloading and accessing the HTML file (I assume that's what you meant ) work with Wordpress, and what code would I be using?

Comment: I found a ready to use plugin for you https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-web-scrapper/

Comment: If it fits your needs, please +1 my answer, I added it there too